# Cordova + Framework7 + Gmaps.js integration (Unable to click markers)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, google-maps

I've created a simple android app that displays a map and a bunch of markers using gmaps.js

```
myApp.onPageInit('location', function (page) {

    document.getElementById('map-canvas').setAttribute("style","height:350px");

    map = new GMaps({
          div: '#map-canvas',
          lat: 28.385234,
          lng: -81.563874
        });
    loadMarkers();
});


function loadMarkers(){
    var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(25.25,-80.80);
    createMarker(loc, "This is a place" , redMarker);

};
    function createMarker(markerLoc , title , color){

      map.addMarker({
        lat: markerLoc.lat(),
        lng: markerLoc.lng(),
        title: title,
        icon: color,
        click: function(e) {
           alert('Location: ' + title);
  }
```

So, the map loads up just fine.  The markers all show up as well.  I can pan over the map, zoom in & zoom out.  However, nothing will fire off the click-event.

I've looked at: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/events/events.html along with Framework7 documention; however, neither makes reference to my problem

Edit 1:
I also looked into something like this but the event never fires

$.event.special.tap = {
         setup: function() {
           var self = this,
             $self = $(self);

```
       $self.on('touchstart', function(startEvent) {
         var target = startEvent.target;

         $self.one('touchend', function(endEvent) {
           if (target == endEvent.target) {
             $.event.simulate('click', self);
           }
         });
       });
     }
```

};

Comment: Unable to click where? please add that information to your original question, and respond in the comment.

Comment: Updated to reflect-  by click I meant the individual markers.  I could use cordova google maps but then I can't use the emulator and have to attach to the phone which I'd prefer to avoid for the time being

Comment: You need to write that in you question. The reason for this is most people read the question to see if it applies to them; they do not read the comments for that. FWIW: you are looking for the answer in the wrong place.